# How to correctly configure cinder charm to use loopback device for storage?

Tags: 14.04, juju

I am using the cinder charm (cs:trusty/cinder-4) and am trying to deploy on a machine with only a single disk.  What's the right way to specify using a loopback file?

Based on examples I have seen, I am putting

> block-device: "/srv/cinder.data|750G"

in a config file.  However, when I try to create a volume in cinder, I get an error.  The cinder logs indicate the volume group can not be found.  When I SSH into the machine, I can see that the file gets created, and is the right size, but the loopback device and volume group have not been created (verified by running "losetup -a" and "vgs")

```
root@4fwa3:~# vgs
No volume groups found
```

The only thing resembling an error in /var/log/juju/unit-cinder-0.log on the machine running cinder is:

```
2014-07-17 19:02:06 INFO config-changed   No physical volume label read from /dev/loop0
2014-07-17 19:02:06 INFO config-changed   Failed to read physical volume "/dev/loop0"
```

---

### Config Files:

/etc/cinder/cinder.conf (written by Juju):

```
[DEFAULT]
 .
 .
volume_group = cinder-volumes
```

config file used when running "juju deploy cinder --config=openstack.cfg":

```
cinder:
   openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-icehouse
   block-device: "/srv/cinder.data|750G"
   overwrite: “true”
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the error in logs, Have you verified in `/etc/cinder/cinder.conf` has the same volume group specified that you have created for loopback. Also verify by restarting all the cinder services

```
for i in api schedular volumes; do service openstack-cinder-$i restart; done
```

[This](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/2/html/Getting_Started_Guide/chap-Deploying_Volume_Services.html) might be of some help to you.

Hope that helps!!